dbeaver - snowflake key pair authentication not working as documented by Snowflake
Wondering what is the right way to use .p8 file for authentication for Snowflake from Debeaver
i created private_key_file and private_key_pwd and added the as user driver properties . still dbeaver takes user_id/password path and not RSA key Pair Authentication method ( community Edition of Dbeaver )

Based on the Dbeaver documentation, private key authentication is supported in lite+ editions but not in the community edition. You are better off using Snowflake Extension for Vscode for private key authentication. I use it occasionally; it is quite a code.

thanks. Wonder why Snowflake would put things out there without validating

This is from Dbeaver. They made p8 authentication part of lite+ addition. Vscode plugin is from snowflake
